# Is there an easy way to change duplicate ConnectionStrings in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, settings, connection-string

I wonder if any of you got a suggestion on how to easy change different setup when using different ConnectionStrings (and possibly other settings too). Currently, when debugging with different ConnectionStrings, I uncomment/comment the one I want to use/don't want to use.

Is there a way to group a collection of settings and use a single value to determine which settings to use?

I don't meen the possibility to have a nested web.config, as Release.web.config and a Debug.web.config, because I HAVE TO use the Debug configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Your application could have a single class responsible for handing out connection string values. Given a parameter it would pull the appropriate string from the .config files.

IMO you should be doing this anyway in case you change the connection string name - if you encapsulate what can change within a class the app is easier to manage.

I don't think you can add some conditional logic directly to the .config files to do this for you.

Comment: sorry - but maybe I've missed your point - 2 thoughts - (i) surely providing a configurable parameter to a class would require an edit to config - full circle? (ii) Out of interest, why do you think one should do this anyway - are you suggesting one may change `<add key="connString1" value="..." />` to `<add key="connString2" value="..." />` or am I still missing your point? Personally, I use the OP's approach of commenting in/out.